# SQL Server : create a foreign key with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm designing a new database for a company, trying to keep strict constraints with foreign keys etc for integrity. I have a table `[Member]` which holds companies on the system. This table has a column of `[internalContact]` for the user in our company who deals with this member which has a foreign linked to the users table by user id.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to assign a condition to the foreign key, since the users table contains internal and external users. ie. for the field to only accept a user id where the user type is 5. Can this be done, or can I only control this in my application code?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplication of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409033/sql-server-conditional-foreign-key-constraints

Comment: I think you can create check constraint.Also this is ideal scenrio for Instead of Trigger .IMHO,Instead of trigger will be more optimize.Am I wrong ?

Comment: You might be able to do this check using a trigger as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072627/rollback-transaction-from-trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a check constraint for this.
(The code is untested some syntax errors will be in there)

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
   P_Id int NOT NULL,
   LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   FirstName varchar(255),
   Address varchar(255),
   City varchar(255),
   InternalContactId
   CONSTRAINT chk_Person CHECK (isInternalUser(internalContactId) > 0)
)

ALTER TABLE Member
ADD FOREIGN KEY (InternalContacId)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

Then just create a function `isInternalUser` that returns 1 if user in ok to be an internal contact

```
CREATE FUNCTION isInternalUser ( @userId int(10) )
  RETURNS int
  AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @tmp int
        SELECT @tmp = count(*)
          FROM users
        WHERE userId = @UserId and <check to see if user is internal>
      RETURN(@CtrPrice)
  END
GO
```